# update a value in a cell and all other cells will be automatically changed

Tags: c#, excel

For example, I have a spreadsheet excel. I want to read it using C#.

In the spreadsheet, I have two or more cell:

```
A1 = 0
B1 = A1 + 7
```

Is it possible that if I change the value of A1 to 1 using C# and then the B1 cell will be automatically updated?

Comment: Are you doing an Excel plugin or this is a standalone program which is reading the Excel document?

Comment: it is a standalone program to read an excel document. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second cell will auto update. Here's some code using MS Excel Object Model (include Microsoft.Interop.Excel.dll):

```
using System;

namespace exceltest2
{
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application excel = null;
            Workbook wb = null;
            try
            {
                // run Excel 
                excel = new Application();
                excel.Visible = false;

                // Open file
                wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(
                    @"D:\test.xlsx", Type.Missing, false, // Read-Only?
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                // Read worksheets
                Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;

                // Select worksheets
                Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item("Table1");

                Range range = (Range)ws.get_Range("A1", "A1");

                // Check Values #1
                Console.WriteLine(ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value2.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ws.get_Range("A2", "A2").Value2.ToString());

                range.Cells[1, 1] = 15;

                // Check Values #2
                Console.WriteLine(ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value2.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ws.get_Range("A2", "A2").Value2.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                wb.Save();
                wb.Close(false, null, null);
                excel.Quit();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access Excel Sheets with C# with help of OleDbConnection , OleDbDataAdapter and DataSet. Here is a sample, how to modify a excel file and cell values: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-update.htm

Comment: in my case, the excel file is very complex so i can not query it with Id for a column, I need to locate to a cell using a cell value for example: B1